# GlusterFS Geo Replication: gsync peer_gsec_create command not found

Tags: glusterfs

My condition right now is

0. i have 4 server, all of them were centos 8-minimal based
1. i have created a volume named `gv0` and replicated it to 2 other server (total 3 nodes, GFS-1 | GFS-2 | GFS-3) and it works normal, i can store/read files from another client node
2. i want to create a geo replication for `gv0` from the GFS-1 node to another node named GFS-4 and it's on different LAN network
3. i saw [this tutorial](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_gluster_storage/3.1/html/administration_guide/sect-Preparing_to_Deploy_Geo-replication#Setting_Up_the_Environment_for_a_Secure_Geo-replication_Slave) and followed it till executing this command on the GFS-1 node

> gluster system:: execute gsec_create

it gives me an error said: `gsync peer_gsec_create command not found.`

what i can do with this? i haven't found any solution to this on Google, please help me

Answer (score 1):

Please try *yum install glusterfs-geo-replication*

Thanks